# oracle sql developer: 00904. 00000 - “%s: invalid identifier”

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
STUDENT_101.ADDR_STREET_DIRECTION,ADDR_ZIP,ADDR_LINE_1 AS ADDR_MSTR_SID,
STUDENT.COUNTRY_1 AS COUNTRY_1,
STUDENT. LOCATION_ID AS LOCATION_CODE
FROM STUDENT
Left Join STUDENT on STUDENT.LOCATION_ID = 101_LOCATION_REF.LOCATION_ID ;
```

i have checked my database and all tables exist.

101_LOCATION_REF is causing error.
STUDENT_101 and 101_LOCATION_REF are tables.

can anyone help me?

Comment: What is `STUDENT_101` and `101_LOCATION_REF`?  And how do you expect to join a table (`student`) to itself without aliases?

Comment: give us table definitions as your query is not complete. you reference tables such as 101_LOCATION_REF that do not appear anywhere else

Comment: @kevinsky What are table definitions? Did you mean table Description?

Comment: Is this `FROM STUDENT LEFT JOIN 101_LOCATION_REF ON` what you want to do?

Comment: @ForguesR Yes, I need the matching columns from Student table and the 101_LOCATION_REF table using the common column LOCATION.ID......
using left join

Comment: Look at Aaron D answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining student to itself, when you want to join it to location.  You need to state the table you're joining TO after join.  Change this:

```
Left Join STUDENT on STUDENT.LOCATION_ID = 101_LOCATION_REF.LOCATION_ID
```

To this:

```
Left Join 101_LOCATION_REF.LOCATIONID on STUDENT.LOCATION_ID = 101_LOCATION_REF.LOCATION_ID
```

Lastly, you're trying to select columns that aren't in either of your tables, student or location.

```
SELECT STUDENT_101.ADDR_STREET_DIRECTION,ADDR_ZIP,ADDR_LINE_1
```

If you want these columns, you need to also join their tables (student_101 and ADDR).  Joins can be tough to conceptualize at first, I'd suggest spending a little time reading up on them.